# Error no matching method even though there should be one

Tags: julia

Recently, I've been trying to add the following function to the median method of `Statistics.jl`. I did it like this: I defined the following: `median(f::Function, v) = median(f.(v))` and `median(f::Function, v::AbstractArray; dims=:) = median(f.(v), dims)`. However, when I run `median(abs, [1, -22, 3])`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching median(::Vector{Int64}, ::Colon)

Closest candidates are:
  median(::AbstractArray; dims)
   @ Statistics ~/github/Statistics.jl/src/Statistics.jl:897
  median(::Function, ::Any)
   @ Main REPL[15]:1
  median(::Any)
   @ Statistics ~/github/Statistics.jl/src/Statistics.jl:881

Stacktrace:
 [1] median(f::Function, v::Vector{Int64}; dims::Function)
   @ Statistics ~/github/Statistics.jl/src/Statistics.jl:828
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[17]:1
```

I don't understand why Julia is not considering `median(::Function, ::Any)` as a matching method.

Comment: Its seems that there is some code missing here thats complicating matters, for example, the stacktrace shows that its actually calling a method from Statistic.jl, specifically `median(f::Function, v::Vector{Int64}; dims::Function) @ Statistics ~/github/Statistics.jl/src/Statistics.jl:828`, but its unclear where `dims` is, or why there is a `::Colon` somewhere in the stacktrace? What are you not telling us? :)

Comment: You're right, I've also added the method ```median(f::Function, v::AbstractArray; dims=:) = median(f.(v), dims)```. I didn't post it because I thought it wasn't important to comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

Because `median(f::Function, v::AbstractArray; dims=:)` is more *specific* (in terms of type) than `median(f::Function, v)` (and because the `dims` keyword argument has a default value and so is optional), that's the method that's getting called when you do `median(abs, [1, -22, 3])`.

The specific error here is because that function then calls `median(f.(v), dims)`, placing `dims` as a positional argument. Since it's a keyword argument, the call should be `median(f.(v), dims=dims)` (or `median(f.(v); dims)`, with the semicolon).

For your purposes, that's probably the only method you want to define: `median(f::Function, v::AbstractArray; dims=:) = median(f.(v); dims)`. Since `median` without a `dims` argument defaults to `:` anyway, your first method definition `median(f::Function, v) = median(f.(v))` is redundant here.